# Creating a Pivot Table in Pandas (SqlAlchemy)

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a pandas dataframe that combines all children into one row

```
class Parent(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'parent'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String())
  class = Column(String())

  all_distance = relationship('Distance', back_populates='parent')
  all_weight = relationship('Weight', back_populates='parent')

class Distance(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'distance'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  distance = Column(String())
  finished = Column(String())

  parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
  parent = relationship('Parent', back_populates='all_distance')

class Weight(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'weight'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  weight = Column(String())
  height = Column(String())

  parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
  parent = relationship('Parent', back_populates='all_weight')
```

Tables with some data:

```
parent
ID | Name | Class
1  | Joe  | Paladin
2  | Ron  | Mage
3  | Sara | Knight

distance
ID | distance | finished | parent_id
1  | 2 miles  | yes      | 1
2  | 3 miles  | yes      | 1 
3  | 1 miles  | yes      | 1
4  | 10 miles | no       | 2

weight
ID | Weight | height | parent_id
1  | 5 lbs  | 5'3    | 1
2  | 10 lbs | 5'5    | 2
```

The goal is to create a pandas dataframe that would look like this:

```
1 | Joe  | Paladin | 2 miles  | yes  | 3 miles | yes  | 1 miles | yes  | 5lbs  | 5'3
2 | Ron  | Mage    | 10 miles | no   | None    | None | None    | None | 10lbs | 5'5
3 | Sara | Knight  | None     | None | None    | None | None    | None | None  | None
```

How would I do that?

I've gotten somewhat close

```
df = pd.read(db_session.query(Parent, Distance, Weight).join(Distance).join(Weight).statement, db_session.bind)
```

which gives me the data frame of everything joined together.

```
list(df.columns.values)

['id', 'name', 'class', 'id', 'distance', 'finished', 'id', 'weight', 'height']
```

How do I prevent the same column headers? ie - id is now 3 times

However when I try to make a pivot table:

`df.pivot(index="id")` it is returning an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5194, in pivot
    return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py", line 400, in pivot
    indexed = self.set_index(cols, append=append)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3909, in set_index
    level = frame[col]._values
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2688, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2698, in _getitem_column
    result = self._constructor(self._data.get(key))
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4130, in get
    raise TypeError("cannot label index with a null key")
TypeError: cannot label index with a null key
```

Comment: Pandas pivoting is not related to SQLAlchemy. Since you have no issue with sourcing the joined data, consider removing class lines not directly needed for your question. Also, did you look into [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)?

Comment: I've just spent an hour trying to look into this for you.  Thanks for that!  But I was getting somewhere with pandas.merge().  It connects dataframes much like sql's join() functions.  Using Inner/out/left/right approaches.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to pass 'id' as index so the pivot fails. It should be:

```
df.pivot(df.index,"id")
```